# multiple ajax calls not working asynchronously (slow TTFB)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've some simple ajax calls to populate drop down lists:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { GetDropDownData('http://mysite/controller/action/parameters1', '#ddl1') });
..
window.addEventListener('load', function () { GetDropDownData('http://mysite/controller/action/parameters4', '#ddl4') });

$.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        crossDomain : true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $(id).html(data);
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            $(id).html("error : " + reponse.responseText);
        }
    });
```

**if I use them individually are fast, but used together are slow.** This is evident in the images below.
The first time I use 1 call and it is fast, the second time I use 2 calls and the previous becomes slow now. The same with multiple calls.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why this? And, can I solve it avoiding to merge the calls in a single call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session locking? One call comes in, locks the session, the second has to wait for the first to finish

Try switching session off and see if it improves

(I had the same problem once)

NB This answer only applies if the calls are asynchronous (as per the other comment)

http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/

Comment: Thanks a lot, obviously the calls are async, however I solved it adding the attribute on the action method as says your link (great article)